# How do I yield values from a different class inside a Kotlin sequence?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a complex tree walker in Kotlin that walks a massive tree, and I want it to output values via a yield() so that it doesn't have to walk the entire tree if I only want to, say, extract a single value.  I can't seem to get the syntax correct however.  Grossly simplified, what I want is to be able to do something like this:

```
class TreeWalker {
    
    fun traverse() {
        
        // not allowed
        //yield("foo")
        
    }
}

fun main() {
    val s = sequence<String> {
        val tw = TreeWalker()
        tw.traverse()
    }
    println(s.take(1))
}
```

The sequence examples I can find online all call yield() from inside the sequence block, not from a separate class/method.  How do I do this?

Comment: I believe you are doing this as an excercise. It is important to understand what `yield` actually do. It does not return anything right away, it is a promise of returning something. Doc here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/-sequence-scope/yield.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using yield in nested object in Kotlin sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690229/using-yield-in-nested-object-in-kotlin-sequence)

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  It looks like I want to be using a callback flow.  FYI the data structure in question is for dictionary word lookup, and is implemented not as a trie but as a ternary tree, which I only just learned about for this purpose.  It's efficient for lookup but has a lot of nodes -- about a million for a 350K-word dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Only suspend functions can be paused and resumed. Assuming you want this to work without coroutines (on your own end, since `sequence` actually runs a sort of lazy coroutine under the hood), the TreeWalker class will need to be able to track the state of where it was in the tree. The `traverse()` function should resume where it left off and return a single item. Here's a made-up simplified example that just searches a 2D array rather than walking a tree:

```
class TreeWalker {
    private var depth = 0
    private var positionAtDepth = 0
    
    fun traverse(): String? {
        for (level in depth until maxDepth) {
            depth = level
            for (position in positionAtDepth until maxPosition) {
                positionAtDepth = position
                val item = someTree[level][position]
                if (isAMatch(item)) {
                    return item
                }
           }
        }
        return null
    }
}

fun main() {
    val s = sequence<String> {
        val tw = TreeWalker()
        while (true) {
            tw.traverse()?.let { yield(it) } ?: break
        }
    }
    println(s.take(1))
}
```

Comment: This is close enough to my TreeWalker implementation that I get the idea.  I would have to do a refactor to keep state like this, but I think this is a viable solution.