# How to propagate closing to a chain of flows in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I am using kotlin and I wanted to stream over a possibly huge resultset using flows. I found some explanations around the web:

- [Callbacks and Kotlin Flows](https://elizarov.medium.com/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf)
- [Use Flow for asynchronous data streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63690229/using-yield-in-nested-object-in-kotlin-sequence)

I implemented it and it works fine. I also needed to batch the results before sending them to an external services, so I implemented a chunked operation on flows. Something like that:

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.chunked(chunkSize: Int): Flow<List<T>> {
  return callbackFlow {
    val listOfResult = mutableListOf<T>()
    this@chunked.collect {
      listOfResult.add(it)
      if (listOfResult.size == chunkSize) {
        trySendBlocking(listOfResult.toList())
        listOfResult.clear()
      }
    }
    if (listOfResult.isNotEmpty()) {
      trySendBlocking(listOfResult)
    }
    close()
  }
}
```

To be sure that everything was working fine, I created some integration tests:

- first flow + chuncked to consume all rows, passed
- using the first flow (the one created from the jdbc repository) and
  applying take operator just to consider few x items. It passed correctly.
- using first flow + chunked operator + take operator, it hangs forever

So the last test showed that there was something wrong in the implementation.
I investigated a lot without finding nothing useful but, dumping the threads, I found a coroutine thread blocked in the *trySendBlocking* call on the first flow, the one created in the jdbc repository.
I am wondering in which way the chunked operator is supposed to propagate the closing to the upstream flow since it seems this part is missing.
In both cases I am propagating downstream the end of data with a *close()* call but I took a look the take operator and I saw it is triggering back the closing with an *emitAbort(...)*
Should I do something similar in the callbackFlow{...}?
After a bit of investigation, I was able to avoid the locking adding a timeout on the *trySendBlocking* inside the repository but I didn´t like that. At the end, I realized that I could cast the original flow (in the chunked operator) to a SendChannel and close it if the downstream flow is closed:

```
 trySendBlocking(listOfResult.toList()).onSuccess {
    LOGGER.debug("Sent")
  }.onFailure {
    LOGGER.warn("An error occurred sending data.", it)
  }.onClosed {
    LOGGER.info("Channel has been closed")
    (originalFlow as SendChannel<*>).close(it)
  }
```

Is this the correct way of closing flows backwards? Any hint to solve this issue?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `trySendBlocking` instead of `send`. You should never use a blocking function in a coroutine without wrapping it in `withContext` with a Dispatcher that can handle blocking code (e.g. Dispatchers.Default). But when there's a suspend function alternative, use that instead, in this case `send()`.

Also, `callbackFlow` is more convoluted than necessary for transforming a flow. You should use the standard `flow` builder instead (and so you'll use `emit()` instead of `send()`).

```
fun <T> Flow<T>.chunked(chunkSize: Int): Flow<List<T>> = flow {
    val listOfResult = mutableListOf<T>()
    collect {
        listOfResult.add(it)
        if (listOfResult.size == chunkSize) {
            emit(listOfResult.toList())
            listOfResult.clear()
        }
    }
    if (listOfResult.isNotEmpty()) {
        emit(listOfResult)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Tenfour04. At the end I decided to use send and it worked. I have decided to keep callbackFlow{...} because send(..) seems to protect in case of backpressure (consumer slower than producer) while the documentation for emit(...) doesn't say anything in case of buffer full.

Comment: The default behavior with the `flow` builder is to suspend on `emit()` calls until the previous value is collected. Typical way to handle backpressure with Flows is to call the `buffer` operator on the Flow. So, if you want a general purpose `chunked` function, the above would be the way to do it because it doesn't make assumptions about how to handle backpressure. It's left to the code that calls it to tag it with a buffer and overflow strategy specific to the use case if necessary.